# How to find List of unindexed file in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, solr4

How can i find the list of UN-indexed file.I just want to perform a task i want to get all those file that is UN-indexed and want to fix and make indexed.
I m using alfresco 5.0.

**How to find the reason why the file failed to get indexed**?

Comment: With the old lucene indexes, there was a special property you could search for to find nodes where the transformation for index failed - [nint / nitf / nicm](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Finding_nodes_by_content) - maybe try that with SOLR and see if the same thing was carried over?

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine, it will give you a list of nodedb IDs, which you can then use to run the REINDEX action separately for each one of them.

https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode

Comment: Can anyone tell me How to find the reason why the file failed to get indexed  in alfresco ?

Comment: Your best bet is to check the SOLR log. If there are no errors in it, try changing the debug level and see if you'll get something then.

Comment: in solr report i am confuse in two tags can anyone explain it  **<long name="Index error count">7</long>   and  <long name="Index unindexed count">217</long>**

Comment: Hi Lista I am using the api that you suggest (https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode) in this its giving only 10 records at a time is there any parameter through that i can increase the records.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query on Node Browser by using fts-alfresco as search type -

```
+TYPE:"content" AND (+cm\:isIndexed:'False' +@cm\:isContentIndexed:'False')
```

The **cm:indexControl** aspect enables you to control indexes for the control items. The aspect exposes the following two properties to allow configuration of indexing of nodes to which it is applied.

- ***cm:isIndexed*** ((content + metadata)): This property controls whether the node is indexed or not.
- ***cm:isContentIndexed***: This property controls whether the node content (binary) is indexed or not. Setting this to false inhibits
  full text indexing of the document binary.

Please refer this Alfresco [wiki](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/admin-indexes.html) for more details.

Comment: but we can't find node refrence with this how can we get properties or trasaction id ?

Comment: actually i want to reindex all unindex file one by one i dont wanna use reindexed all file api. have  u any idea to do that one by one?

Comment: I have web-script to get the status of unindexed file in alfresco [https://localhost:8443/solr4/admin/cores?action=REPORT&wt=xml][1].but i want to know which file is get failed to get index so i can find the nodeid and try to reindex using [https://localhost:8443/solr4/admin/cores?action=REINDEX&nodeid=01f7d6d1-dfd4-49e2-989c-f73a853013f4][2].can any one tell me how to find out the list of unindexed file or nodeid of the unindexed file??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered more or less [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401983/find-reason-why-a-file-fails-to-get-indexed/36406857)

The reason for failed content indexing couldn't be found in solr since the repo is responsible for transforming the content to text. So you need to find the reason for failed transformations in the repo's / transformation engine's log.

A node having the `cm:indexControl` aspect attached (e.g. `cm:isContentIndexed` does not necessarily mean the transformation failed. Alfresco sets this property to avoid indexing/transformation)

To summarize: There is no easy way to report the reason why content transformation and therefore indexing failed. You should check the logs on the repo / t-engine side.

To repair unindexed or failed transactions you should run the action=FIX report described in the docs:[Troubleshooting Solr Index](https://docs.alfresco.com/search-community/concepts/solr-index-fix.html)