# alfresco buildonly indexer for searching the properties created on the fly

Tags: java, solr, alfresco

I am using the latest version of alfresco 5.1 version.
one of my requirement is to create properties (key / value) where user enter the key as well as the value.

so I have done that like this

```
    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
    props.put(QName.createQName("customProp1"), "prop1");
    props.put(QName.createQName("customProp2"), "prop2");
    ChildAssociationRef associationRef = nodeService.createNode(nodeService.getRootNode(storeRef), ContentModel.ASSOC_CHILDREN, QName.createQName(GUID.generate()), ContentModel.TYPE_CMOBJECT, props);
```

Now what I want to do is search the nodes with these newly created properties. I was able to search the newly created property like this.

```
public List<NodeRef> findNodes() throws Exception {
    authenticate("admin", "admin");
    StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
    List<NodeRef> nodeList = null;
    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
    props.put(QName.createQName("customProp1"), "prop1");
    props.put(QName.createQName("customProp2"), "prop2");
    ChildAssociationRef associationRef = nodeService.createNode(nodeService.getRootNode(storeRef), ContentModel.ASSOC_CHILDREN, QName.createQName(GUID.generate()), ContentModel.TYPE_CMOBJECT, props);
    NodeRef nodeRef = associationRef.getChildRef();
    String query = "@cm\\:customProp1:\"prop1\"";
    SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
    sp.addStore(storeRef);
    sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
    sp.setQuery(query);
    try {
        ResultSet results = serviceRegistry.getSearchService().query(sp);
        nodeList = new ArrayList<NodeRef>();
        for (ResultSetRow row : results) {
            nodeList.add(row.getNodeRef());
            System.out.println(row.getNodeRef());
        }
        System.out.println(nodeList.size());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return nodeList;
}
```

The alfresco-global.properties indexer configuration is

```
index.subsystem.name=buildonly
index.recovery.mode=AUTO
dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
```

Now my question is

Is it possible to achieve the same using the solr4 indexer ?
Or Is there any way to use buildonly indexer for a particular query ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using "buildonly" (which is really a deprecated Lucene) in the first place?

Comment: I know its deprecated, only If I mention "buildonly" as the indexer I can search for properties which I have created (as specified in the question)

Comment: Meaning, if you go with SOLR you can't find the document? Do you get an error, or is the document simply not found?

Comment: I dont get any error, the result set is empty

Answer (score 1):

In your query 
`String query = "@cm\\:customProp1:\"prop1\"";`
remove **cm** as you are building the QName on the fly so  it does not come under cm i.e. (ContentModel) properties. So your query will be

```
String query = "@\\:customProp1:\"prop1\"";
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I tried your solution it works with the **buildonly** indexer.
Since I am using indexer **solr4** your query results in empty set.

Answer (score 0):

First, double check if you're simply experiencing **eventual consistency**, as described below. If you are, and if this presents a problem for you, consider switching to CMIS queries while staying on SOLR.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/solr-event-consistency.html

Other than this, check if the node has been indexed at all. If it has, take a closer look at how you build your query.

[How to find List of unindexed file in alfresco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932393/how-to-find-list-of-unindexed-file-in-alfresco/36084988#36084988)

Comment: Hi Lista, Thank you for your efforts. I have asked the same question in alfresco IRC channel and it seems like I can not search for the properties created on the fly. The property has to be attached to a model !!

Comment: I see, I haven't realized those props are not in your model, haven't worked with that case at all to be totally honest.

What's the reason for omitting them from the model?

Comment: well the requirement was to have properties associated with a specific node, where user can enter the key as well as value of his choice and these properties should not be visible(available) to other nodes. The user should be able to search a node based on the created properties !!